# Jersey Client IPv6

Tags: java, rest, jersey, ipv6

Can I use Jersey Client to connect to a REST resource using IPv6?

I'm getting this error:

```
com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: java.net.MalformedURLException: For input string: ":94ea:d2bc:c189:209c%10:8100"
    at com.sun.jersey.client.urlconnection.URLConnectionClientHandler.handle(URLConnectionClientHandler.java:128)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.handle(Client.java:551)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.handle(WebResource.java:556)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.access$200(WebResource.java:69)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource$Builder.put(WebResource.java:475)
    at com.bmc.aps.agent.jersey.JerseyClient.put(JerseyClient.java:168)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Caused by: java.net.MalformedURLException: For input string: ":94ea:d2bc:c189:209c%10:8100"
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:601)
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:464)
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:413)
    at java.net.URI.toURL(URI.java:1081)
    at com.sun.jersey.client.urlconnection.URLConnectionClientHandler._invoke(URLConnectionClientHandler.java:139)
    at com.sun.jersey.client.urlconnection.URLConnectionClientHandler.handle(URLConnectionClientHandler.java:126)
    ... 8 more
```

In the exception the ip is cut (`:94ea:d2bc:c189:209c%10` instead of `fe80::94ea:d2bc:c189:209c%10`).
In debug, I can see that the web resource URI is OK.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the answer.

Jersey Client expect to get the IP with square parentheses `[]`.

In this example - `[fe80::94ea:d2bc:c189:209c%10]` instead of - `fe80::94ea:d2bc:c189:209c%10`.